# A question about $H^{m,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded and connected open domain. m is a non-negative integer, $1 \le p< \infty$. For any $u \in \overline{\Omega}$,define a norm ||u||=$(\sum\limits_{|\alpha| \le m} \int_{\Omega}{|\partial^{\alpha} u(x)|^{p}} dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.
My problem is: how to verify the triangle inequality of the norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to realize that it is the product measure which works in this case:
\begin{align*}
d\mu_{m}\times dx,
\end{align*}
where $d\mu_{m}$ is the counting measure corresponds to $\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}$.

For such a function $u$, it can be viewed as a function on the product space $\{\alpha:|\alpha|\leq m\}\times\Omega$ that
\begin{align*}
u(\alpha,x)=\partial^{\alpha}u(x),
\end{align*}
so you have
\begin{align*}
\|u\|=\|u\|_{L^{p}(d\mu_{m}\times dx)}.
\end{align*}
The triangle inequality is due to the Minkowski's inequality in a more general measure space $(\{\alpha:|\alpha|\leq m\}\times\Omega,d\mu_{m}\times dx)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply much. I almost know your mean, but I haven’t learned the product measure and the generalization of the Minkowski’s inequality. Can you recommend some reference about them? Thanks again.

Comment: Any real analysis book will contain that, see Royden for example.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: Please do not violate [Quality Standards on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C131.7888).